# SQL Server : error assigned name to a local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with assigning a database name to a variable. When I do this, I get a message that there is no such database.

What am I doing wrong that this script doesn't work?

```
DECLARE @db_name varchar(10) 
SET @db_name = 'xxx'

ALTER TABLE [@db_name].[dbo].[Table_Name] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]
GO

ALTER TABLE [@db_name].[dbo].[Table_Name] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name] CHECK (QUERY)
GO

ALTER TABLE [@db_name].[dbo].[Table_Name] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]
GO
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
> Database '@db_name' does not exist.
>
> Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
> Database '@db_name' does not exist.
>
> Msg 2702, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
> Database '@db_name' does not exist.

Comment: What is your table name ?

Comment: Table has name `BigBookEntry`. However, it's rather like the table is called, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say for example that you have a table created like this:

```
create table xxx(id int
                 CONSTRAINT AK_TransactionID UNIQUE(id))
```

Then you will need to cerate two variables(one for the object name and one for the query to be executed...):

```
DECLARE @db_name varchar(10) ;
DECLARE @query nvarchar(500) ;
```

Set them to the values you need:

```
SET @db_name = 'xxx';
set @query = 'ALTER TABLE ['+ @db_name +' ] DROP CONSTRAINT [AK_TransactionID]';
```

And then execute the query:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a7ae25d6264a0de2a8042d00fa9cc94)

Answer (score 1):

A query - meaning all text until each GO command - is **compiled** before it is run.

Database names inside queries have to be **be known at compile time**, because the database + any table or column you specify are inspected by the query compiler to see if they are valid.

This means that Database names + Table names + Column names all *cannot* come from @-variables, because at compile time variables don't yet exist and have no value.

The fix is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @db_name varchar(10) = 'xxx'
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @db_name + '].[dbo].[Table_Name] DROP CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in SQL Server, you cannot pass schema, database, table or column names as a parameter - if you want to do this, you must use dynamic SQL. You could do the below to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @db_name = [xxx]

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE' + @db_name+ '.[dbo].[Table_Name] DROP CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]'
EXEC (@SQL)

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE' + @db_name + '.[dbo].[Table_Name]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name] CHECK  (QUERY)'
EXEC (@SQL)

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE' + @db_name + '.[dbo].[Table_Name] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Constraint_Name]'
EXEC (@SQL)
```